# Can't run server with Deno and Servest

Tags: typescript, deno

I was trying to run a simple server in Deno and typescript but I keep having this error:

```
error: TS2739 [ERROR]: Type '{ localAddr: { transport: "tcp"; hostname: string; port: 
number; }; remoteAddr: { transport: "tcp"; hostname: string; port: number; }; rid: 
number; close(): void; closeWrite(): Promise<void>; read(p: Uint8Array): Promise<...>;
write(p: Uint8Array): Promise<...>; }' is missing the following properties from type 
'Conn': readable, writable

const conn: Deno.Conn = {
    ~~~~
at https://deno.land/x/servest@v1.3.1/testing.ts:41:9
```

I use this code from the servest documentation:

```
// @deno-types="https://deno.land/x/servest@v1.3.1/types/react/index.d.ts"
import React from "https://dev.jspm.io/react/index.js";
// @deno-types="https://deno.land/x/servest@v1.3.1/types/react-dom/server/index.d.ts"
import ReactDOMServer from "https://dev.jspm.io/react-dom/server.js";
import { createApp } from "https://deno.land/x/servest@v1.3.1/mod.ts";

const app = createApp();
app.handle("/", async (req) => {
  await req.respond({
    status: 200,
    headers: new Headers({
      "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
    }),
    body: ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
      <html>
        <head>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          <title>servest</title>
        </head>
        <body>Hello Servest!</body>
      </html>,
    ),
  });
});
app.listen({ port: 8899 });
```

I searched everywhere and I can't find an answer, I'm using deno v1.19.1

Comment: You're creating a new object with the type `Deno.Conn`. `Deno.Conn` requires a whole bunch of properties, which you are not setting at the subsequent lines you didn't share. I suspect you either 1) shouldn't use `Deno.Conn` type, or 2) incorrectly instantiating `Deno.Conn`. Maybe you missed a factory method or a constructor?

Comment: The example I extract it directly from the servest documentation, that's all the code, the Deno.Conn is generate by servest I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the files that is downloaded by Deno as part of your program's dependency tree is the following:

https://deno.land/x/servest@v1.3.1/testing.ts

In the error message you can see that there is a TypeError when typechecking this file, because `Deno.Conn` is missing the `readable` and `writeable` properties.

If you visit https://deno.land/x/servest@v1.3.1/testing.ts#L41 you can see it declares a variable `conn` of type `Deno.Conn` which does not have these properties indeed. Deno [added `readable` and `writeable` to Deno.Conn in 1.19](https://deno.com/blog/v1.19#files-network-sockets-and-stdio-are-now-native-web-streams), so the type of `conn` declared in Servest 1.3.1 is not the same as the type of `Deno.Conn` in Deno 1.19. You could inform the authors of the code of this issue so they can fix it. In the meantime you could use Deno 1.18, where this type has not changed yet.